# turn this jquery into an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-snippets

I have this snippet below and I';m trying to make it an if/else statement and I'm getting syntax errors...

```
<!--script for changing Number of Columns-->
$(window).load(function(){
var idx = $('select[name="numNames"]').children('option:selected').index();
if (idx < 7){
$('.oneColumn').click(function() {
$('.IH_pINameRow').removeClass("floatLeft ");
$('.IH_pINameRow').addClass("floatNone ");
$('.odd').removeClass("leftMargin");
$('.even').removeClass("rightMargin ");
$('.pI_nameText').removeClass("textAlignLeft textAlignRight");  
$('.pI_nameText').css('font-size', '2em');
$('.pI_nameText').addClass("1col");
$('.pI_nameText').removeClass("2col");
$('label.twoColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
$('label.oneColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
} else {
    return false;
}
}); //error is here//
if (idx > 3){
$('.twoColumn').click(function() {
$('.IH_pINameRow').removeClass("floatNone ");
$('.IH_pINameRow').addClass("floatLeft ");
$('.odd').addClass("leftMargin");
$('.even').addClass("rightMargin ");
$('.pI_nameText').css('font-size', '1em');
$('.pI_nameText').removeClass("1col");
$('.pI_nameText').addClass("2col");
$('.odd').removeClass("textAlignLeft");
$('.even').removeClass("textAlignRight");
$('.even, .odd').addClass("textAlignCenter");
$('label.twoColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
$('label.oneColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
$('label.leftAlignment').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
$('label.centerAlignment').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
} else {
    return false;
}
});
});
```

I'm also not sure if the code scope is correct such that the idx variable is available to the second function...

Comment: So how do you propose we pitch in here? Perhaps you could have given us more to work with?

Comment: Sure, basically, I'm getting an error on the first else line, I'm probably missing a bracket etc.  I'm looking for some help with the formatting I guess.

I'd like to to do all the things in the function if a select menu is less than a certain index and do nothing if it's more.  I'm using buttons with labels and a .click function otherwise I would use a check to see if it's selected, unfortunately that's not working with how I have it set up.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  Newbs should be forgiven for things like indenting etc.  and not knowing common practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this into bare parts, and fix the indentation. Then use some static analysis to compact the if statements.

```
<!--script for changing Number of Columns-->
$(window).load(function(){

  function oneColumnClick() {
    $('.IH_pINameRow').removeClass("floatLeft ");
    $('.IH_pINameRow').addClass("floatNone ");
    $('.odd').removeClass("leftMargin");
    $('.even').removeClass("rightMargin ");
    $('.pI_nameText').removeClass("textAlignLeft textAlignRight");  
    $('.pI_nameText').css('font-size', '2em');
    $('.pI_nameText').addClass("1col");
    $('.pI_nameText').removeClass("2col");
    $('label.twoColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
    $('label.oneColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
  }

  function twoColumnClick() {
    $('.IH_pINameRow').removeClass("floatNone ");
    $('.IH_pINameRow').addClass("floatLeft ");
    $('.odd').addClass("leftMargin");
    $('.even').addClass("rightMargin ");
    $('.pI_nameText').css('font-size', '1em');
    $('.pI_nameText').removeClass("1col");
    $('.pI_nameText').addClass("2col");
    $('.odd').removeClass("textAlignLeft");
    $('.even').removeClass("textAlignRight");
    $('.even, .odd').addClass("textAlignCenter");
    $('label.twoColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
    $('label.oneColumn').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
    $('label.leftAlignment').css('background-position', '-104px -52px');
    $('label.centerAlignment').css('background-position', '-104px -26px');
  }

  var idx = $('select[name="numNames"]').children('option:selected').index();
  if (idx < 7){
    $('.oneColumn').click(oneColumnClick);
    if (idx > 3){
      $('.twoColumn').click(twoColumnClick);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: monstrosities is right!  This is what happens when you have an artist write code :0

Comment: I've edited the answer to be a bit more useful.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's awesome.  for whatever reason, when I apply this to my page, it doesn't work.  If I change the greater than or less than operator to greater than or equal it starts working again...not much help with out code I'm sure, here's the page previous to your additions so you can see where I'm coming from: http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/

Comment: Seems like it's mostly working. What's the exact case where this doesn't work?

Comment: here's a fiddle with your changes:http://jsfiddle.net/Dp2Pq/1/

when you select say 8 names, it shows the appropriate text areas and makes them required, it also sets the layout to be 2 column.  Now if I click on the single column "button" it does nothing, when it should only allow it to go 1 column when there are less than 7 names.  basically I';m only allowing 2 columns for over 3 names and only allowing 1 column for less than 7 names.  Does that make sense?  it's starting to not make sense for me anymore :)

Comment: It seems that jquery hasn't loaded yet. Use `$(function(){` rather than `$(window).load(function(){`.  http://jsfiddle.net/Dp2Pq/2/

Comment: So, you want to completely disallow the one-column button if more than  7 are selected, and completely disallow the two-column when less than 3 are selected?

Comment: yes that's where I';m going with it

Comment: ok then put that test in the button handler. http://jsfiddle.net/Dp2Pq/3/

Comment: That's awesome Joe, I know I can';t PM cuz my rating isn't high enough, but would you like to maybe make some extra cash by helping me out with this project?

Comment: No thanks, I'm just taking a break at work.

Comment: alright, well if I have any more questions would you be willing to help on your free time?  I only ask cuz I'm in the final stretch and juts trying to pull this all together :)

Comment: I don't do that sort of thing. Just make a new SO question.

Comment: I guess a real question I've been trying to find an answer to is how to condense all this code into one "script" I mean , it's all over the place...literally :) I really need to be able to call things like the oneColumnClick function in more than one place and as of now they are separated into separate scripts...really a newbie way of doing it.

Comment: In my jsfiddle, I attached the function to the button with `$('.oneColumn').click(oneColumnClick);`. You can now trigger it anywhere. `$('.oneColumn').trigger('click')` will trigger a click of the button.

Comment: as an aside, do I want to have my if statements within the function?  shouldn't i set up the two functions, and then say if this do function one, but if this other thing  do function 2?  I ask because even with the stuff you changed/added I can still go to two columns even if there are 3 names...NEVERMIND, I had my greater than less than values wrong...thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:** Please indent your code, otherwise it's really hard to find any errors.

### Where is the error?

You have to close `$('.twoColumn').click(function() {` **before** the `if (idx > 3){`, but if opens before the click function.

### Why did you make that error?

You do not make these kinds of errors when you indent your code correctly. I was so kind and did this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7snmR/ < Looks weird, right?

Comment: Thanks Gap, I'm npot a programmer by nature, pretty much an artist with a technical leaning.  I'm very appreciative for the breakdown...and thanks for throwing that into a fiddle, much easier to see :)